# Max rep is not saving. Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Im creating an application where users can save their maximum repetition (RM) of a movement, including how many reps and the weight reached. When i try to create the RM it gives the following error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RmsController#create Couldn't find
>   User with 'id'=

This is my RM controller:

```
class RmsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :load_user, only: [:create]

  def new
    @rm = Rm.new
    @rm.user_id
  end

  def create
    @rm = current_user.rms.build(rms_params)
    if @rm.save
      flash[:success] = "Max rep created"
      redirect_to rms_path
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def index
    @rms = Rm.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
  end

  def destroy
    @rm = Rm.find(params[:id])
    @rm.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Max rep deleted"
    redirect_to rms_path
  end

  private
    def rms_params
      params.require(:rm).permit(:user_id, :content, :quantity, :max)
    end

    def load_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
  end
```

Rm's new view html.erb:

```
 <aside class="col-md-8">
    <div class="rm_form">
      <%= form_for(@rm) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <%= f.select :content, ['Back squat', 'Front squat', 'Deadlift',
                                'Sumo Deadlift', 'Sumo Deadlift High Pull',
                                'Power Snatch', 'Power Clean',
                                'Squat Clean', 'Muscle Snatch',
                                'Clean & Jerk', 'Thruster', 'Push Jerk',
                                'Split Jerk', 'Press',
                                'Push press', 'Cluster', 'Overhead Squat']%>

        <%= f.label :max, "Max reps" %>
        <%= f.text_field :max, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :quantity, "Weight lifted" %>
        <%= f.text_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

        <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
      </aside>
</div>
```

RM's index view html.erb:

```
<% @rms.each do |rm| %>
  <li>
    <%= p rm.content, rm.quantity, rm.max %>


  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<div class="center">
<%= link_to "Create new max rep", new_rm_path(@rm), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Current user is defined at sessionshelper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
       @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
     elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
       user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
       if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
         log_in user
         @current_user = user
       end
     end
   end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :users
  resources :rms
  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

I would like to now why it is giving me this error and how i can fix it. Thanks

Comment: How is `current_user` defined? Can you show us the code?

Comment: Updated the post! With sessions helper

Answer (score 1):

The `user_id` is getting a `""` value (blank), so no `User` will be found with `id=""`.

That is because even if it is blank, it will evaluate to `true` in `if (user_id = session[:user_id])`. So you need to validate for that; using `presence` method could fit your need:

```
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id].presence)
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id].presence)
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

`presence` method will return `nil` when the value of the object is blank (or `nil`), or will return the value of the object otherwise; and `nil` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I updated the code (added `presence` in the `elsif`). But it is likely to give you another error since `@current_user` will not be set if both `session[:user_id]` and  `cookies.signed[:user_id]` are `nil`.

Comment: it gives me the same error again. i updated with the config routes, maybe it an error there i dont know

Comment: Is the error still in the same place (i.e. `RmsController#create`)?

Comment: Forget this answer, go with Sebastian's.

Comment: For taking your time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new object that already has a relationship with your user, so, the user_id will be mandatory. So you can create it directly using its params, in this case `rms_params`, you don't need to create it referring firstly to the `current_user` and then build it as an association.

Check changing your `create` method from:

```
@rm = current_user.rms.build(rms_params)
```

Just to:

```
@rm = Rms.new(rms_params)
```

And as in your form in your `app/views/rms/new.html.erb` you're already assigning manually the value for the `user_id`:

```
# 1 as the first user created as example
<input value="1" type="hidden" name="mark[user_id]" id="mark_user_id">
```

There's no need to do nothing in your controller, as I've seen in your `rms_controller` the `@rm.user_id` under the `RM.new`.

The current_user method returns the user using `find_by` taking the user's id through the sessions:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

Check [this](https://bitbucket.org/hnhm/rms_current_user) repo to see how it works.

Comment: it still gives me the same error, you are telling me to comment the method current_user?

Comment: This make more sense! Nice catch.

Comment: Check your "tweaked" `current_user` helper @Cesar.

Comment: Yes @Gerry, I don't understand the overwrite to the `current_user` method.

Comment: what you mean with tweaked

Comment: Your modified method, `current_user` should work well in this situation, I'll add a repo to check it.

Comment: i created this current_user method with the help of this guide https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Missed out completely `before_action :load_user`, so `current_user` seemed to be the only place where`create` queries for a  `User`, thus the only place to get that error (`id=`). Eliminating possible blanks could fix the error.

Comment: According to the Michael's tutorial he's following to create his own authentication, the current_user helper will be able anywhere, there's no need to load the user before saving a new user. Anyways I think there's a lack of info.

Comment: I agree, there's no need to load user in `create` action. @Cesar, maybe you could try removing `before_action :load_user, only: [:create]`, i think that would eliminate the error.